# Youtube API 3.0 - Failed to start the resumable upload exception 0

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, youtube-api

I created a PHP script to directly upload video to a YouTube Channel using Youtube API 3.0 and Google Api Php Client, as described in this tutorial: https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide

Differently from this tutorial, I generate The OAuth access token using the OAuth 2.0 Playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) and then I stored the json data into a MySQL database (instead of using a text file).

Everything worked right for a couple of days, but today I get this error:

```
Caught Google service Exception 0 
message is 
Failed to start the resumable upload (HTTP 400: youtube.video, Bad Request)

Stack trace is 
#0 /home2/xxx/public_html/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php(134): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->getResumeUri() 
#1 /home2/xxx/public_html/_upload_video.php(98): Google_Http_MediaFileUpload->nextChunk('\x00\x00\x00\x14ftypqt \x00\x00\x00...') 
#2 {main}
```

several times. Despite this, the video is uploaded correctly into YouTube!

Row 98 is:

```
$status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
```

I really can't understand where the problem is. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: What extension does the video that you're trying to upload have? Is it a .mov by any chance?

Comment: Hi Andrei, no it isn't. It's a mp4. But other users experimented issues on uploading mov... Do .mov files have something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check to see if you have a channel created in youtube?